# percentage calculation visualization problem

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, area

I have a 13*13 square a total of 169 blocks out of which I select 22 blocks area should be approximately 13%.

I tried to use the same concept in the game of poker calculator(Flopzilla) in counting % of hand combinations but that shows the value of blocks to  20%. I am not sure what I am missing.
Let me explain to you with a picture

In the following picture pink blocks(22 blocks) are the ones I am considering of 169 block squares (total) and counting Flopzilla shows the pink blocks account for ~20% instead of ~13
could someone please help me understand what I am missing and why I am wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those squares represent the kinds of pairs of cards you can have in poker. The squares are not equally likely. For example, the square representing two aces AA can happen in six different ways ("combos"): A♠A♡ A♢A♡ A♣A♡ A♣A♠ A♣A♢ A♠A♢.  In contrast, the square representing a king and ace of the same suit (denoted AKs) can only happen four ways: A♠K♠,A♡K♡, A♣K♣, A♢K♢.  So, if you pick a random pair of cards (i.e. a random square in the grid), you're more likely to get two aces (AA) than an ace and king of the same suit (AKs).

---

How likely is each square in the grid?

- Each square above the diagonal (i.e. golden squares) represents two cards of the same suit (a "suited pair"). Each one can happen in four ways. (Each square has 4 combos.)
- Each square below the diagonal (i.e. pink or red) represents two cards of different suits (an "off-suit pair"). Each one can happen in twelve ways. (Each square has 12 combos.)
- The ones on the diagonal (i.e. blue) are pocket pairs, such as two kings. In a single deck, they must have different suits. Each one can happen in six ways. (Each square has 6 combos.)

If you pick any two cards out of a deck, there are 1326=52⋅51/2 different outcomes. You could also have calculated this as the total number of "combos" in the 13x13 grid: There are 78 = (13⋅13-13)/2 squares above the diagonal, and the same number below, so the total number of combos is: 78⋅4 + 78⋅12 + 13⋅6 = 1326.

---

How likely are the 22 squares chosen in the picture?

If you choose 22 blocks below the diagonal, you accumulate 22⋅12 = 264 combos. As a fraction of the total number of combos, that's ~0.199 as shown in the figure.

Comment: Thanks a ton !!! for your explanation . I feel silly how I missed out considering all blocks are not equal . Thanks again for your detailed explanation  despite of me posting a trivial question

Comment: @AvinashKoneru Glad it was useful!  The answer wasn't obvious to me at first --- maybe Flopzilla could include the number of combos with each square to make it more clear to everyone! :)